Can I install Debian to a USB disk from a live USB?
I run Arch on my home server and after 2 years of infidelity I want to get back to Debian.
I will install it on a new M2 disk, but for comfort reasons I would like to avoid bringing the tower computer from my home datacenter (the top of a storage shelf) to my screen.
The idea I had was to install Debian by

connecting the M2 to my laptop via USB
start a live Debian USB
install on the M2 drive
plug the M2 to the tower in the DC

Would that work?

It depends. If you assure the bootloader is correctly installed it should work.

You won't know until you try.

You probably have to reinstall grub or use efibootmgr (which grub install uses) to add a new UEFI boot entry to the tower system's UEFI boot menu. You may be able to just directly boot a drive entry using /EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi on M.2 drive and then from inside install reinstall grub. You may have to first update UUID of mount of ESP in fstab. Best to confirm it is correct. You can also use Boot-Repair to reinstall grub. Be sure to use gpt partitioning and have ESP on M.2 drive, or it may use the drive of system you are installing from.
